# Unable to create LINQPad connection EF Core 2.1.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, linqpad, ef-core-2.1

I have a ASP.NET Core 2.1 web application that uses EF core 2.1 that I need to diagnose a LINQ issue with LINQPad. I have installed the latest LINQPad driver for EFCore 2.1.1.4 and when I try to create a new connection by browsing to the web site dll I get the below error:

LINQPad EF Core Driver  X
Assembly 'Debug\netcoreapp2.1\MyBlog.dll' is an .NET Core assembly. Your project must target either .NET Framework or .NET Standard 2.0.

As you can see this is a Net Core App 2.1, is this this issue? Or does someone know what might be the issue?

Orgbrat